# Lining up labels with radio buttons in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap form with some inline radio buttons and a label. I'd like to keep the label on the same line as the buttons, but I can't seem to make that happen. Here's my approach:

```
<form>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Some label</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" value="1"/>
                First
            </label>
            <label class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" value="2"/>
                Second
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GaDbZ/2/

I also tried this:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <label class="control-label">Some label</label>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" value="1"/>
            First
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" value="2"/>
            Second
         </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

But everything is smooshed together. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GaDbZ/3/

How can I get the horizontal spacing from the first one combined with the vertical spacing of the second?

Also, I should note that in real life, I have a bunch of other stuff going on in the form, so I don't want to use `form-horizontal` because it creates funky margins that don't jive with the other stuff I have in there.

Comment: I don't understand what you wnat the end result to be.  You want the label to be inline (e.g. to the left of the radio buttons) but only that ONE label?  The rest you want wrapped below, with the label above?

Comment: @EliGassert right. Or more generally just making this part inline without affecting the layout of the rest of the form.

Comment: So turn the whole thing to horizontal, see what styles are set (firebug, chrome console, etc), and give this control block a special class that sets those same horizontal styles.  Not sure what else to offer.  The stylesheets are pretty basic -- all or nothing.  Either it's horizontal or it isn't; inline or it isn't.  To make overrides you just need to customize the default CSS on your own.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you add the 'radio inline' class to the control label in the solution provided by user1938475 it should line up correctly with the other labels.  Or if you're only using 'radio' like your 2nd example just include the 'radio' class.

```
<label class="radio control-label">Some label</label>
```

OR for 'radio inline'

```
<label class="radio-inline control-label">Some label</label>
```

Comment: The font-size can give the appearance that it is lined up correctly.

Comment: For me,  it works with class="align-middle" on <input>. Try it !

Answer (score 43):

Since **Bootstrap 3** you have to use [checkbox-inline and radio-inline](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls) classes on the label.

This takes care of vertical alignment.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
```

Answer (score 32):

This may work for you, Please try this.

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="controls-row">
      <label class="control-label">Some label</label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" value="1" />First
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" value="2" />Second
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That sort of works, except that the control label is weirdly aligned with the radio labels: http://jsfiddle.net/GaDbZ/4/

Comment: If you wrap the labels containing the checkboxes/radios in a DIV, they will not line up with control label (at least when using form-horizontal).

Answer (score 10):

This is all nicely lined up *including* the field label.  Lining up the field label was the tricky part.

[image]

### HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-5">Create a</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <label class="radio-inline control-label">
            <input checked="checked" id="TaskLog_TaskTypeId" name="TaskLog.TaskTypeId" type="radio" value="2"> Task
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline control-label">
            <input id="TaskLog_TaskTypeId" name="TaskLog.TaskTypeId" type="radio" value="1"> Note
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSHTML / Razor Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Create a", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <label class="radio-inline control-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TaskTypeId, Model.TaskTaskTypeId) Task
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline control-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TaskTypeId, Model.NoteTaskTypeId) Note
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like wrapping the the labels containing the radios in a `div class="col-*-*"` is the key to getting everything aligned.

Answer (score 1):

In **Bootstrap 4** you can use the [form-check-inline](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios) class.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="queryFieldName" id="option1" value="1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="option1">First</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="queryFieldName" id="option2" value="2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="option2">Second</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Key insights for me were:
 - ensure that label content comes *after* the input-radio field
 - I tweaked my css to make everything a little closer

```
.radio-inline+.radio-inline {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best is to just Apply `margin-top: 2px` on the input element.

Bootstrap adds a `margin-top: 4px` to input element causing radio button to move down than the content.