# Radio Button not inline with label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code at [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p1h211uL/)

```
<form>
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"></div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="input_user_id">User ID</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="input_user_id" name="input_user_id" type="text" placeholder="" value="KING0002" readonly>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="input_name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="input_name" name="input_name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="input_password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="input_password" name="input_password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="credit">Credit </label>
        <input class="form-control" id="credit" name="credit_limit" type="text" placeholder="Credit">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="create_member">Can Create Member</label>
            <input type="radio" name="create_member" value="no" checked>No &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="create_member" value="yes">Yes
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am using twitter bootstrap for my textfield, form control class, I tried to add radio button

e.g

```
Can Create Member:  yes [] no []
```

But the output appear that the yes and no are above each other.

How do I change to have a proper inline radio button and the alignment is about same as the textfield regardless of screen resolution ( be it mobile or desktop )

Comment: Maybe this will help :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857909/lining-up-labels-with-radio-buttons-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have given 50% width to all `input` elements. Just exclude `radio` inputs using `not` like bellow

```
.field input:not([type="radio"]) {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p1h211uL/1/)

Comment: Thanks Its work! I will accept answer in 7 mins(due to restriction for new member like me)