# Bootstrap 3 Radio buttons covering labels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <label class="control-label">Ganztägig</label>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-xs-8">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        Nein
        <input value="False" name="Appointment.AktWholeDay" id="Appointment_AktWholeDay" checked="checked" type="radio">
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        Ja
        <input value="True" name="Appointment.AktWholeDay" id="Appointment_AktWholeDay" type="radio">
    </label>
</div>
```

As you can see here http://www.bootply.com/iqEGNLKQvA the label text is covered by the radio button. How Do I make the text align to the radio so it is not covered?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857909/lining-up-labels-with-radio-buttons-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing the label text after the radio button input solves your issue:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
        <input value="False" name="Appointment.AktWholeDay" id="Appointment_AktWholeDay" checked="checked" type="radio"/>
        Nein
</label>
```